# Find out user logged in at specific time on Mac OS X 10.11.x

Tags: command-line, osx, macintosh

I'll like to find out which user was logged in at a particular time that a file was created.

I'm having trouble with the "Last" command when attempting to use the "-t" switch.

Open to any suggestions, the machines are running standard OS X no extra management software.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
> man last

-t tty      Specify the tty.  Tty names may be given fully or abbrevi-
             ated, for example, ``last -t 03'' is equivalent to ``last -t
             tty03''.


> last -t ttys002

home      ttys002                   Sun Jan  3 21:32 - 21:32  (00:00)
```

Comment: I'd like to know who was logged in at 8:32am on December 17th 2015.

Comment: > last | grep 'Sun Jan  3 13:37'

Comment: returns: home      ttys001                   Sun Jan  3 13:37 - 21:32  (07:54)

Comment: But I'm working with time stamps on files & multiple users will possibly be using the machine during the day. I guess I could go back in time until I only have a single line returned. Say "home ttys001 Sun Jan 3 13:37 - 21:32 (07:54)" created a file at 15:29 and that is the time you're working with.

Comment: Find out who was logged in at a particular time
The syntax is as follows to see the state of logins as of the specified time:
$ last -t YYYYMMDDHHMMSS

Comment: you are right mac has -t  option different.